# Are there any restrictions for teleportation at Elturel & Berdusk?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

I think I saw it somewhere that both or only one of these cities prevents teleportation into them or out of them.

But now I can't find any evidence about it.

Could you please tell me if it is true or not?

Comment: What sources are you permitting? Only *5th Edition* sourcebooks? Other sources?

Comment: @Thomas Markov Any sources

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for Berdusk, however Elturel is prominently featured in the Descent into Avernus,

> A plane shift spell transports ****** the wizard and up to eight other creatures to Elturel

So at that time magic obviously isn't protecting it from teleportation. However, if you are aware of the plot, things have happened in the town.

It's worth noting that in the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, it specifically mentions teleportation not working well in High Forest, or Silverymoon, but doesn't mention it at all in Elturgard section (or the Elturel or Berdusk subsections)